# Ormlite RawRowMapper truncated double

Tags: android, database, ormlite

I am using RawRowMapper to load relevant columns from ormlite. RawRowMapper returns all data as String.

The observation is that it truncates the double value.

Example:
Data inserted -> 57.1117146374

Data type used to store the data -> Double

Data from Ormlite when directly queried: -> 57.1117146374 (This is correct and essentially means that ormlite is actually storing the data correctly)

Data from Ormlite when using mapper -> 57.1117 (Truncated data coming as part of String[] resultColumns

Any idea how do I avoid it getting truncated?

EDIT:

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "LAT")
private Double lat;
```

Object Field:

```
private double lat;
```

The key here is that the string in resultcolumns[], I get is already truncated.

Comment: Thanks Gray. That was quick. I edited and added the relevant info.

Comment: I am getting a bad feeling about it now that this might need a patch or a way to pass the data type for dao to intelligently fetch data.

Comment: Thanks keeping fingers crossed. Also let me know of your finding, I will dig into the source as well.

Comment: Hi Gray, was wondering if there is any update on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Data from Ormlite when using mapper -> 57.1117 (Truncated data coming as part of String[] resultColumns

The problem seems to be that getting a `double` value out as a `String` is truncated by Android's `cursor.getString(...)` method.  Not sure why but if the result is extracted by using `cursor.getDouble(columnIndex);` on the same column-index, the full precision is preserved.

The solution here I believe is to map the rows differently.  If you use [`dao.queryRaw(String, DataType[], ...)` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryRaw%28java.lang.String,%20com.j256.ormlite.field.DataType%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String...%29), the double field seems to be extracted appropriately.  Here's a sample from my test class.

```
GenericRawResults<Object[]> results =
        dao.queryRaw(dao.queryBuilder().selectColumns("lat")
            .prepareStatementString(), new DataType[] { DataType.DOUBLE });
CloseableIterator<Object[]> iterator = results.closeableIterator();
try {
    assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
    Object[] objs = iterator.next();
    assertEquals(foo.doubleField, objs[0]);
} finally {
    iterator.close();
}
```

You could also use a custom row mapper and the [`dao.queryRaw(String, RawRowMapper, ...)` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryRaw%28java.lang.String,%20com.j256.ormlite.dao.RawRowMapper,%20java.lang.String...%29) to convert and return a custom object with a `double` field.

Comment: let me try and get back.

Comment: With new DataType[] { DataType.DOUBLE } can I pass a different datatype for each column that I am selecting and will that return the data in the mapper in that same format?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works.  If the value is of the wrong type, I'm not sure what the results are.  For example, if it is the string "foo" and you try to map it to a double, I assume it will fail @PravinCG.

Comment: I have used the iterator method to iterate and create object one by one. I am unable to use the customRowMapper though for this. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: I've added some more tests here that can be used as an example: https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/dao/RawRowMapperTest.java

Comment: Also the online docs have some details about how to do it: http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear, what i meant was that is there a way to use RawRowMapper which takes DataType as Input and returns data accordingly instead of truncating like in this case. Also the data types need not be of same type for all columns. So something like `public MyClassObject mapRow(String[] columnNames, Object[] resultColumns)` Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding @PravinCG but I just added a feature that will be in 4.47 that allows another way to map from `DataType[]` to an `Object`.  See: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryRaw(java.lang.String, com.j256.ormlite.field.DataType[], com.j256.ormlite.dao.RawRowObjectMapper, java.lang.String...)